# How to use Selenium in python or request to extract the <img src links and other contents?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, request, css-selectors, webdriverwait

https://insuretechconnect.com/speakers/

Greetings, I want to extract the speakers' information from the above website and I want to have their Name, Title, Company, img src link, and Description.

[image]

However, my code can only extract the Name, title, and the company.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'XXX\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://insuretechconnect.com/speakers/')
```

`speakers_info=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.awsm-personal-info')))
speakers_info_fulllist = []
for e in speakers_info:
   speakers_info_fulllist.append(e.text.split('\n'))`

Are there any better ways to extract information for all speakers (either Selenium or the Request)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the speaker **Eran   Agrios**'s information, i.e. *Title*, *Company*, *Image Link* and *Description* using only [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

  driver.get("https://insuretechconnect.com/speakers/")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='awsm-personal-info']//h3[contains(., 'Eran')]//preceding::img[1]"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='awsm-personal-info']//h3[contains(., 'Eran')]//preceding::img[1]"))).click()
  print("Title is : "+ WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='awsm-modal-content-inner']/h2[contains(., 'Eran')]//following::h3[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  print("Company is : "+ WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='awsm-modal-content-inner']/h2[contains(., 'Eran')]//following::h3[2]/b"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  print("Image Link is : "+ WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='awsm-modal-content-inner']/h2[contains(., 'Eran')]//preceding::img[1]"))).get_attribute("src"))
  print("Description : "+ WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='awsm-modal-content-inner']/h2[contains(., 'Eran')]//following::p[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Title is : Head of Global Go To Market, Financial Services Cloud and Wealth &amp; Asset Management
  Company is : Salesforce
  Image Link is : https://n68y02w29js2mtetnvfd871d-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Eran-Agrois-500x500.png
  Description : Eran Agrios leads the Go To Market strategy for Financial Services Cloud at Salesforce. Eran has over 15 years of experience in customer relationship management technology. She has spent the last 10 years at Salesforce working with Financial Services companies on innovation and digital transformation. Most recently, her focus has been on the success of Salesforce’s first industry product, Financial Services Cloud.
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code works so well! Glad to learn the Locator Straregies.

Answer (score 1):

This solution can do this.

```
speakers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='awsm-modal']//div[@class='awsm-grid-card']")
print("Total Speakers : ", len(speakers))

    for i in range(len(speakers)):
        print("Speaker Info # ",i+1)
        details = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='awsm-modal']//div[@class='awsm-grid-card']"+"["+str(i+1)+"]")
        print(details.text)
        imgsource = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='awsm-modal']//div[@class='awsm-grid-card']"+"["+str(i+1)+"]//img")
        print(imgsource.get_attribute('src'))
```

The output will be,

> > Total Speakers :  242  Speaker Info #  1  ERIK ABRAHAMSSON  CEO DIGITAL FINEPRINT
> >     https://n68y02w29js2mtetnvfd871d-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Erik-Abrahamsson-1-500x500.jpg

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is cool! BTW, I also want to get the text after the <h3> <p> "Eran Agrios leads the Go To Market strategy..." How can I do that? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

To get an attribute with selenium, you need the method `driver.fine_element_by_css_selector('path').get_attribute('nameoftheattribute')`

For the description, I don't know where is located, but probably you'll need another line of code: it really depends from where is it.